# Google Play Store App Reject - React native

Tags: react-native, google-play

[App Reject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjo4B.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kudwo.jpg)I have tried to upload my App on store, My App rejected every time .
** Issues ** : Violation of permission Policy.
Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
You declared Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler) as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
Please either:
• Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
• Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality

Answer (score 0):

Go android folder in your project and locate manefest.xml file in it.
Remove all the unnecessary permissions that were generated during project setup.

Google play like it that, you should only ask for permission that your App is using and you must state it in data policy how you are using the data in the App

Make sure you test all the functionalities before you upload.

Google is trying to prevent logic bomb here.

Comment: i already removed unwanted permission files from manifest. Same time Google play console --> App content --> Sensitive permissions and APIs --> SMS and call log permissions && android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
android.permission.READ_SMS. Here what should i select from the checkbox and I selected default sms handler only.. can you tell ?

Comment: I'm not asking any run time sms permission and user enter the OTP manually and submit and also not taking any call log also.. i cross checked is any library used sms or call permission but nothing happen.

Comment: **"I selected default sms handler only."**  By this you are telling google play that, any SMS intent that come into the phone will be receive by you.. That is you will be responsible for opening and sending messages  like Truecaller App or any default message app preinstalled by the OS

Answer (score 0):

Finally App was published.
If you app continuous reject, Next time going to before submit check the following file locations / list available.
Upload new build and play store automatically remove the previous uploaded file(if already 3 build upload and got rejected & again upload a new 3 build with latest version code )